# RNPickerSelect crashes with correct input for items

Tags: react-native

What am I doing wrong with my React Native PickerSelect?
It crashed all the time without a warning.

```
import RNPickerSelect from 'react-native-picker-select';

  getCompanies = () => {
    var items = this.state.companies.map(obj => ({
      key: obj.id,
      label: obj.name,
      value: obj.id,
    }));
    return items;
  };
```

This is rendered:

```
<RNPickerSelect
    onValueChange={value =>
      this.setState({company: value})
    }
    items={this.getCompanies()}
  />
```

But when I open the view where this should be rendered, my App crashes.

Comment: you set state for this.state.company but your getCompanies mention this.state.companies, may I know how are they related? More codes probably needed to identify your problem in between.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial that just a fetched array which i map to an object in the method

Comment: codes need clarity, we need to see where this.state.company translate to this.companies. You want us to help you solve a problem you cannot just provide part of codes, but hiding whatever is in between. At the moment there doesn't seem anything wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't comment cause of low reputation.

I had similar issue, make sure "@react-native-picker/picker" is also installed.

for more reference look [here](https://github.com/lawnstarter/react-native-picker-select).

Comment: Nope, that was not it. I installed it. Couldnt do the `npx pod-install` though, because it's Android

Comment: Try `console.log(items)` in `getCompanies()` to check what data it is returning. Also to check if issue is in **items** prop try dummy array for test like `[{key: 7, label: 'name', value: 7}]` like this, Otherwise code looks correct to me.
Also what react-native version are you using?

Comment: That also fails ```<RNPickerSelect items={[{key: 7, label: 'name'},{key: 72, label: 'namex'}]}/>```

Comment: Tried same, It's working for me. Are you sure issue is with **RNPickerSelect**?
Try commenting this tag probably issue is something else.
also I'm using version **8.0.4** and react native version **0.63.4**.

Comment: Thnx! I added some reputation to your account ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same problem, I downgraded react native version to 0.63.0, it resolved the issue